# Slice Up array according to content

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a somewhat complicated task of slicing and dicing an array of data into a sensible JSON Object. The first step is to slice the array into smaller arrays based on the content of the elements.

In this simplified version I want to break one big array into a series of smaller arrays defined by the word "that."

Given this array:

```
that, thing, thing, that, thing, that, thing, thing, thing
```

I want to return:

```
[that, thing, thing],
[that, thing],
[that, thing, thing, thing],
```

Comment: Could you please post code that you have attempted so we can guide you better?

Comment: So, to clarify, you want to split a single array into an array of arrays that start with the key value `that`?

Comment: I don't see what could possibly be a *"sensible JSON Object"* in the context of your question....

Comment: As Sterling is suggesting, post the real code as any solution given on those "that" and "thing" strings couldn't match the real code problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is easy to do with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var array = ["that", "thing", "thing", "that", "thing", "that", "thing", "thing", "thing"];

console.log(array.reduce(function(prev, cur, idx, arr) {
    if (cur === "that") {
      // start a new sub-array
      prev.push(["that"]);
    }
    else {
      // append this token onto the current sub-array
      prev[prev.length - 1].push(cur);
    }

  return (prev);
}, []));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4hacdud/)

Comment: awesome new array function to learn with .reduce(), works wonders!

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = ['that', 'thing', 'thing', 'that', 'thing', 'that', 'thing', 'thing', 'thing'];
var subArrays = [];

var subArrayItem = [];
arr.forEach(function(arrItem) {
    if(arrItem == 'that') {
        if(subArrayItem.length) // avoid pushing empty arrays
            subArrays.push(subArrayItem)
        subArrayItem = []
    }
    subArrayItem.push(arrItem)
})

if(subArrayItem.length) // dont forget the last array
    subArrays.push(subArrayItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be manual work. I recommend a combination of [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (to find the "that") and [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) (to remove the relevant sub-array).

```
var input = ["that", "thing", "thing", "that", "thing", "that", "thing", "thing", "thing"];
var output = [];
for (var idx = input.indexOf("that", 1); idx !== -1; idx = input.indexOf("that", 1)) {
    output.push(input.splice(0, idx));
}
output.push(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick `reduce` should fix it:

```js
var src = ["that", "thing", "thing", "that", "thing", "that", "thing", "thing", "thing"]

var dest = src.reduce(function(p,d) {
    if (d === "that") {
        p.push([d]);
    } else {
        p[p.length-1].push(d);
    }
    return p;
},[]);

$("#json").text(JSON.stringify(dest));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="json"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lastIndexOf, slice and unshift.

```
function test (a, b, item) {
  var i = a.lastIndexOf(item);
  while (i != -1) {
    b.unshift(a.slice(i));
    a = a.slice(0, i);
    i = a.lastIndexOf(item);
  }
  return b;
}

var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [];

test(arr1, arr2, 1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Using nodejs to run the result is:

```
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]
```